Unable to connect MySQL (xampp) using Python
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="")

if conn.is_connected():
    print("Successful")
else:
    print("Not Successful")`

I think my everything is ok in environment variable setup, mysql is also running in the system, python works properly, xampp also works well, the value of host, user are also correct. But I am unable to connect with Mysql using python. This is not even showing any error. There comes no output at all.
Output
Whenever I run the program, I get no output at all, I am pretty much sure the problem is happening in the second line. but not sure what is happening and how to solve.
I tried using Mysql workbench, doesn't work.
I am expecting to control my database from this python program

Why are you passing  the -u flag?

I am not passing it, I am clicking on 'Run Code' using mouse. It is automatically calling this.

which version of mysql is being used? also which version of the mysql connector?

mysql version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.32-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491
connector version: mysql-connector-python 9.1.0

can you try without the -u?

I did, doesn't change anything.

Since the application does not produce any output it is impossible to guess what is happening. You should run it in the debugger so you can see whether the connect call is successful or not. It would also maybe help to actually make a call to the database.
